# Class inheritance

Tags: python, class

Consider the following code:

```
class A(object):
    a = []

    @classmethod
    def eat(cls, func):
        print "called", func
        cls.a.append(func)


class B(A):
    @A.eat
    def apple(self, x):
        print x

    A.eat(lambda x: x + 1)


print A.a
```

Output : 
`called <function apple at 0x1048fba28>
called <function <lambda> at 0x1048fbaa0>
[<function apple at 0x1048fba28>, <function <lambda> at 0x1048fbaa0>]`

I expected `A.a` to be empty as we have not even created an object.How are the `2` function getting added here?What exactly is causing `eat` to get called `2` times?

Comment: All statements in a class are executed when loading the class, e.g. `class A: print('hello')` would print "hello" when loading the class. Both `@A.eat` and `A.eat()` are executed statements when the class is loaded, even without the `print A.a` you would get the first 2 printed outputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a [class definition is an executable statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions).

Any code within the body of the class (but outside of function definitions) will be executed at run-time.

If you want to have code that only runs whenever a class object is instantiated, put it in the `__init__` class method.

Note that [some tutorials](http://sthurlow.com/python/lesson08/) get this wrong, which no doubt adds to the confusion:

> No code is run when you define a class - you are simply making
>   functions and variables.

This is simply wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The class body definition is executed when the module is imported.

And that also means the decorator is executed as well, passing the `apple` function object to `A.eat` and then binding the return value to the name of the function you passed (`apple`).

You can read more about Python's execution model here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html